# meaning of "rub shoulders with" in context

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

What does it mean? What does rub shoulder with what?

> ....when the confines of narrow specialism are no longer appropriate and philosophical, literary, scientific, ideas **rub shoulders** with relative ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rub shoulders** means meet or interact closely. Since in a crowd your shoulders would rub together with other people close to you.

So in your example the ideas from these fields are often used together closely.

Comment: thanks. Could we say "A and B rub shoulders" without using "with"? Here, does "with" refer to "relative ease" or to the verb?

Comment: refers to "with relative ease"